# Knowing when not to normalize with ffmpeg loudnorm

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, audio-normalization

I've written a script that uses the ffmpeg loudnorm filter to normalize the audio for video files - it does a first pass to analyze the file, then a second to normalize it using those values.

Ideally I'd like to make it not carry out the second step if the file doesn't need to be normalized. Is there any way of figuring this out from the first step? What it results in is a set of parameters like this:

```
input_i=-15.06
input_tp=-0.89
input_lra=16.50
input_thresh=-26.28
output_i=-16.76
output_tp=-1.50
output_lra=12.70
output_thresh=-27.61
normalization_type=dynamic
target_offset=0.76
```

I'm wondering if any of these values can be used to decide if the file needs to be normalized or not. I've looked in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loudnorm) and it tells you what the ranges of these values can be, but not really what they *mean.*

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The main use of loudnorm is to adjust the input to a target integrated loudness level, so it depends on what you would like the output loudness to be. In the example log, the input is measured at -15.06. Is that good enough? That's for you to decide.

Comment: @Gyan thank you, yes, that's perfect. Knowing which parameter is the most useful one here is what I was interested in, I realised it would always be a subjective value. If you add this as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main use of loudnorm is to adjust the input to a target integrated loudness level, so it depends on what you would like the output loudness to be. In the example log, the input is measured at -15.06. Is that good enough? That's for you to decide.